# How to set TextBlock extension property programmatically

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, textblock

I have an extension for textblock, to allow formatted "Inlines" to be assigned. I've followed the approach provided by @max to create this extension.

[Format part of the text of TextBlock using iValueConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058814/format-part-of-the-text-of-textblock-using-ivalueconverter)

Now, what I need to do is to be able to set this FormattedText property programmatically as the UI element, which is the parent of the TextBlock is being created dynamically.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" local:TextBlockEx.FormattedText="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LabelFormatConerter}}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the methods that were clearly declared in the answer to your linked question, or do you copy without looking? Maybe something like this?:

```
TextBlockEx textBlockEx = new TextBlockEx();
textBlockEx.SetFormattedText(textBlockEx, new Run() { Text = "Hello World" });
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You *really* should ask every thing at once, rather than asking additional questions once your question had been answered. I can 't even provide a full answer to your *second* question, as you removed the `Binding.Path` and `Source` from the `Binding`. To create your `Binding` in code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("PropertyOfYourDataSourceObject");
binding.Source = YourDataSourceObject;
binding.Converter = new SomeConverter();
textBlockEx.SetBinding(TextBlockEx.FormattedTextProperty, binding);
```

Please refer to the [How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I did get to this point, as you suggested in your response. But, I noticed that I didn't actually include the line of code that I need the help on. I'm looking to translate this XAML to C# code that I could do from code-behind.

Comment: <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" local:TextBlockEx.FormattedText="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LabelFormatConerter}}" />